# How to execute web app function without giving edit access permission of apps script to user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have created a web app defined a doGet method in it and published it with permissions as:

**Execute the app as:** Me.

**Who has access to the app:** Anyone, even anonymous.

But when I share it with users they are not able to access it. The URL which I have shared with users is [https://script.google.com/macros/s/[ID]/exec](https://script.google.com/macros/s/%5BID%5D/exec)
When users try to run or open the link it will ask for edit access permission. Shown in below image:
[image: Asking for edit permission]

I don't want to give edit access of the script to users. How can users run the function or web app, without giving users edit access permission of the script?

Comment: Republish it. Make sure you're using the correct url(Deployment id varies).

Comment: @TheMaster I'm using a redirect URI which is https://script.google.com/a/macros/[Gsuit]/s/[ID]/usercallback this is asking for edit access.

Comment: Well Don't use `/usercallback`  then